# How to handle cases where parent Eloquent model does and does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Given a `Dues` and `Payment` Laravel Eloquent models with the following defined relationships:

```
    /**
     * Get the payment(s) for this set of dues
     */
    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the Dues to which this payment belongs.
     */
    public function dues()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Dues::class, 'dues_id'); // custom key because Laravel assumes no s on model name
    }
```

where more than one `Payment` can be assigned to a `Dues` model (i.e. broken into multiple payments), I am trying to create a `Payment` and associate it to the `Dues` model in my controller, and address the case where the `Dues` model may or may not exist. My thought is to use Eloquent methods to find an existing model if it exists"

```
    public function store(StorePaymentRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        $calculator = new DuesRenewalCalculator($validated['user_id']);
        $year = Carbon::now()->year;

        $dues = Dues::firstOrNew(
            ['user_id' => $validated['user_id'], 'year' => $year],
            [
                'year' => $year,
                'type' => 'renewal',
                'member_dues' => $calculator->dues,
                'building_assessment' => $calculator->buildingAssessment,
                'work_hours_assessment' => $calculator->workHours,
                'nra_dues' => $calculator->nra,
                'associate_dues' => $calculator->associate,
                'junior_dues' => $calculator->juniors,
                'total' => $calculator->total
            ]
        );

        $dues->user()->associate($user);
        $dues->save();

        $payment = new Payment([
            'payment_date' => $validated['date'],
            'amount' => $validated['amount'],
            'refund' => $validated['refund'],
            'reference' => $validated['reference'],
            'comments' => $validated['comments'],
            'mode' => $validated['mode']
        ]);

        $payment->dues()->associate($dues);
        $payment->save();

        return Redirect::route('user.dues.index', ['user' => $validated['user_id']])->with('success', 'Work Hours saved');
    }
```

This code works perfectly if both models are new, but if `$dues` already exists, I get an error that `Column dues_id cannot be null.` on `$payment->dues()->associate($dues);`. Is this because `associate()` only works when the parent model doesn't exist?

If i try

```
$dues->payments()->save($payment);
```

I get

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dues_dues_id' in 'field list'
```

What is the easiest way to handle both possibilities (that the parent `Dues` model does or doesn't exist)?

Comment: Why not associate the `Dues` to `Payments` instead of `User` ?

Comment: Because they are associated to a particular user. Each Dues can be made of multiple payments.

the hierarchy is User -> Dues -> Payment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the model instance returned from `firstOrNew()` has an `id` if it's an existing one and doesn't if it is creating a new one, I was able to get my process to work like so:

```
    public function store(StorePaymentRequest $request, User $user)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();

        $calculator = new DuesRenewalCalculator($validated['user_id']);
        $year = Carbon::now()->year;

        $dues = Dues::firstOrNew(
            ['user_id' => $validated['user_id'], 'year' => $year],
            [
                'year' => $year,
                'type' => 'renewal',
                'member_dues' => $calculator->dues,
                'building_assessment' => $calculator->buildingAssessment,
                'work_hours_assessment' => $calculator->workHours,
                'nra_dues' => $calculator->nra,
                'associate_dues' => $calculator->associate,
                'junior_dues' => $calculator->juniors,
                'total' => $calculator->total
            ]
        );

        if (!$dues->id) {
            $dues->user()->associate($user);
            $dues->save();
        }

        $payment = new Payment([
            'payment_date' => $validated['date'],
            'amount' => $validated['amount'],
            'refund' => $validated['refund'],
            'reference' => $validated['reference'],
            'comments' => $validated['comments'],
            'mode' => $validated['mode']
        ]);

        if (!$dues->id) {
            $payment->dues()->associate($dues);
        } else {
            $dues->payments()->save($payment);
        }

        $payment->save();

        return Redirect::route('user.dues.index', ['user' => $validated['user_id']])->with('success', 'Payment saved');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

$payment->dues()->associate($dues) only works when $dues exists. if you get an error that Column dues_id cannot be null, it means $dues doesn't not exist.